# Passing in a reference of a member of 'this' into a parameter of std::thread

Tags: c++, qt

I need to write a function that isn't part of my class `MainWindow` (this is a Qt project) so that it can be used in a thread, but I also need it to use a member of `MainWindow` inside it. Here is the code I have written:

```
void nameChange(TMAPI *tmapi) {
    tmapi->writeString(0x001bbbc2c, qPrintable(n));
}

void MainWindow::on_button_clicked() {
    std::thread id(nameChange, this->tmapi);
    id.join();
}
```

I get two errors from this (they are the same error but point to different lines of code in the file `<functional>`):

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(TMAPI))(TMAPI*)>
```

Calling `nameChange` like this seems to work:

```
TMAPI tmapi;
std::thread id(nameChange, &tmapi);
```

How can I get the first way to work where I pass in the current object's (`this`'s) instance of tmapi? Thanks.

Comment: It's a TMAPI, no pointer.

Comment: Ahh, you got me. I changed the parameter to `&this->tmapi` and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nameChange` takes a `TMAPI *`. You are trying to pass it a `TMAPI`. Hence the super cryptic error:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<void (*(TMAPI))(TMAPI*)>
```

The `result_of` metafunction is used like `result_of<F(Args...)>`. In this case, that type indicates that you're trying to call a `void(*)(TMAPI*)` with a `TMAPI` - which is not a valid thing to do.

So just pass a pointer like the function expects:

```
std::thread id(nameChange, &this->tmapi);
```